# Load Javascript file depending on parent div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, dom-events

--- Following on from what people have said ---

This is for a multi-page form, which loads the multiple pages in the DOM. The DOM loads page_2_2 and page_3_3 HOWEVER, one has a style property of display:none and the other doesn't. Can the script be done in a way to check which one has display:none and then load the appropriate Javascript file? So for example:

If DIV ID=page_2_2 has style="display:none", then load page2.js otherwise load page1.js?

---

I have two Javascript files... called page1.js and page2.js.

I need a Javascript based if function which says that

IF, the parent DIV ID = page_2_2, then load page1.js, and if the parent DIV ID = page_3_3, then load page2.js, otherwise load nothing.

Comment: Can you paste what you have so far?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have anything so far...

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to make much sense. The parent div ID of what? What are you try to achieve? Is there a reason you cannot just load both files and then call the functions you need from one or other based on the structure of the DOM?

Comment: The parent DIV - i am referring to the DIV which has the IF function. I cannot load both files simultaneously as they are conflicting... otherwise i would not be asking on how to do this.

Comment: It's somewhat difficult for a script to "find itself" on a page, @Miro. That is,  for a script to find the "parent" of the `<script>` tag it is in is not easy; there's no explicit support for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function loadscript(divID) {
    var scriptURL;
    if (divID == "page_2_2")
       scriptURL = "page1.js";
    else if (divID == "page_3_3")
       scriptURL = "page2.js";
    $.getScript(scriptURL);
}
```

It's not complicated, function gets string as paramater.

```
loadscript("page_2_2") // will load page1.js
loadscript("page_3_3") // will load page2.js
```

It's not important what type elementid you passed as string paramater.

---

**EDIT:**

As I understand you have two div and one of them has "none" as display value, so you can do it like this way.

```
<div id="page_2_2" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="page_3_3"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#page_2_2').is(':visible'))
        $.getScript("page1.js");
    else 
        $.getScript("page2.js");
});
```

Comment: Haha, love this.  It's just as vague as the question.  +1

Comment: @Xyan Ewing, Im not sure how much information i can give you on a simple IF... a biography of my site code will not help you in any way.

Comment: an id is an id targeting is the same regardless of what type of element it is. it is important however that an Id is unique

Comment: @Miro, actually we have to know more details about about your basic html code, where is parentDiv? Is it have a static class? I wrote just a javascript function, usage? it's up to you.

Comment: @Miro, True, a biography wouldn't help.  But some code would :P

Comment: @Miro, I had been edited my answer after you shared some more information.

Answer (score 2):

just run a check then load

```
if($('#page_2_2').is(":visible")){
    $.getScript("/page1.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
       console.log(data); //data returned
       console.log(textStatus); //success
       console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
       console.log('Load was performed.');
    });
}else if($('#page_3_3').is(":visible")){
    $.getScript("/page2.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
       console.log(data); //data returned
       console.log(textStatus); //success
       console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
       console.log('Load was performed.');
    });
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/45sV9/)

Comment: UPDATED my answer to reflect the OPs chante in question

Comment: thanks for the working demo... strange its not working on me, must have a conflict somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the div id then inject a script node into the header. Not tested it myself.

```
    if($('#[insert id]').length != 1){ inject script etc }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a feature-based approach where you put your logic in different files based on ***what to use it for*** instead of ***where*** you use it.

Example file structure:

> /Scripts/Utils.js
>   /Scripts/SpecificEditor.js
>   /Scripts/Wysiwyg.js

On pages where you need a wysiwyg you'll reference Wysiwyg.js and on pages you need the "SpecificEditor" you'll reference "SpecficEditor.js".

With your approach your site will be hard to manage when it grows. How do you share logic between pages for example?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
function loadScript(filename){
 var fileref=document.createElement('script')
 fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
 fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

if(document.getElementById("page_2_2")===null){
 loadScript("page1.js");
}else if(document.getElementById("page_3_3")===null){
 loadScript("page2.js");
}
```

It becomes slightly shorter with jQuery, convert the if-else-if block to:

```
 if($(".page_2_2").length==0){
     loadScript("page1.js");
    }else if($(".page_3_3").length==0){
     loadScript("page2.js");
    }
```

You're not being clear about what you mean by "parent" div. In this case, this will load the script if *any* div on that page has that id. You're not supposed to have more than one element with the same id, so I guess this is OK. Otherwise the jQuery `closest()` method will work.

Comment: Thank you... This is for a multi-page form which hides and displays the different pages using css, so in this case, both page_2_2 and page_3_3 divs will be loaded in the DOM. Is there a way to get this to work the way i am thinking of?

Comment: @Miro: Then check the value of `document.getElementById("page_2_2").style.display`

Comment: How would this be with closest()?

Comment: i'm sorry, javascript is clearly not a strong point for me... how would i phrase that?

Comment: @Miro: `if(document.getElementById("page_2_2").style.display=="none"){}`

Comment: Thank you... one thing though... is it possible to get it to print the fileref in the location of the script, rather than look for the <head> tag?

Comment: @Miro: Replace `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)` with `document.getElementById("ID OF SOME DIV").appendChild(fileref)`

Comment: Chrome gives me the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: @Miro, are you sure about your div's ID? it means that you don't have a div#page_2_2

Comment: yes the ID's are correct... to be honest i have been having a bit of javascript problems... the only way to resolve it is to use jquery i think... this has sorted out the problem before... (on different issues)